# When is a generated $\sigma$-algebra complete?

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory

Given a probability space $(E,\mathcal{E},\mu)$, we say that the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{E}$ is *$\mu$-complete* provided that

$$
\text{if}\quad N\in\mathcal{E} \quad\text{with}\quad \mu(N) = 0, \quad\text{then also}\quad \tilde{N}\in\mathcal{E} \quad\text{for any } \ \tilde{N} \subseteq N.
$$

Let now $(F,\tau)$ be a Polish space and $X : E \rightarrow (F, \tau)$ be Borel-measurable (and assume that $\mathcal{E}$ is $\mu$-complete, if necessary).

Which (non-trivialising) conditions on $X$ guarantee that

$$
\text{the $X$-generated $\sigma$-algebra} \quad \sigma(X):=\sigma(X^{-1}(B)\mid B\in\tau) \quad\text{is } \ \mu\text{-complete}\,?
$$

$\phantom{.}$

**Remark:** This question is [cross-posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4806103/when-is-the-generated-sigma-algebra-of-a-borel-measurable-random-variable-com) from the Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: I think there will be no non trivial conditions (maybe $E$ countable). F.i., let $E = F$ and $X$ be the identity. Then your question boils down to "When is the Borel-$\sigma$-algebra complete w.r.to a probability measure $\mu$". I think never if $F$ is not countable.